# How to return user to main menu when using switch statement? Java

Tags: java

I am creating a program that will allow the user to enter a UK airport and an international airport to assess the feasibility of running a flight between them.

I have created a text file that contains the international airport info and read this into an `ArrayList` for flexibility.

I want to return the user to the main menu if the user does not enter a valid international airport. I have used `switch` statement for the menu choices.

File contents/Code/input/output are as shown below.

File Contents:

```
JFK, 
John F Kennedy International, 
5326, 
5486,
ORY, 
Paris-Orly, 
629, 
379,
MAD, 
Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Baranjas, 
1428, 
1151,
AMS, 
Amsterdam Schipol, 
526, 
489,
CAI, 
Cairo International, 
3779, 
3584
```

Code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.IOException;

class Main {

    // menu method 
    static void menu() {
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("| Enter 1 to input airport details                   |");
        System.out.println("| Enter 2 to input flight details                    |");
        System.out.println("| Enter 3 to enter price plan and calculate profit   |");
        System.out.println("| Enter 4 to clear data                              |");
        System.out.println("| Enter 5 to quit                                    |");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  
        System.out.println("Welcome...");
        System.out.println();
        menu();
        System.out.println();

        // reading file
        /*File file = new File("Airports.txt");
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
        System.out.println(fileScan.nextLine());
        //getting all lines from text file
        while(fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(fileScan.nextLine());
        } */
        ArrayList<String> airportList = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("Airports.txt"))) {
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                airportList.add(scan.nextLine().replace(",", "").trim());
            }
            System.out.println(airportList);
        }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\n" + "Enter menu choice: ");
        int menuChoice = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (menuChoice) {
        case 5: 
            System.out.println("You selected >Quit<. Program ending...");
            break;

        case 1: 
            System.out.println("You selected >Enter airport details<");
            System.out.println("\n" + "Enter code for UK airport");
            String ukCode = scanner.next();
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter valid code for overseas airport");
                String overseasCode = scanner.next(); 
                if (airportList.contains(overseasCode) && overseasCode.equals("JFK")) {
                    System.out.println("John F Kennedy International");
                    break;
                } else if (airportList.contains(overseasCode) && overseasCode.equals("ORY")) {
                    System.out.println("Paris-Orly");
                    break;
                } else if (airportList.contains(overseasCode) && overseasCode.equals("MAD")) {
                    System.out.println("Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Baranjas");
                    break;
                } else if (airportList.contains(overseasCode) && overseasCode.equals("AMS")) {
                    System.out.println("Amsterdam Schipol");
                    break;
                } else if (airportList.contains(overseasCode) && overseasCode.equals("CAI")) {
                    System.out.println("Cairo International");
                    break;
                } else {  // ***
                    System.out.println("Not valid input");
                }
                continue; // *** where I want to return user to main menu**
            } while (ukCode.equals("LPL") || ukCode.equals("BOH"));
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Enter 1 to input airport details                   |
| Enter 2 to input flight details                    |
| Enter 3 to enter price plan and calculate profit   |
| Enter 4 to clear data                              |
| Enter 5 to quit                                    |
------------------------------------------------------

[JFK, John F Kennedy International, 5326, 5486, ORY, Paris-Orly, 629, 379, MAD, Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Baranjas, 1428, 1151, AMS, Amsterdam Schipol, 526, 489, CAI, Cairo International, 3779, 3584]

Enter menu choice: 
1
You selected >Enter airport details<

Enter code for UK airport

LPL

Enter valid code for overseas airport

GHGH **(not valid - doesnt exist in text file)**

Not valid input

Enter valid code for overseas airport //**instead of this i want user to return to main menu**
```

Comment: your do-while loop will never end until ukCode changes its value. So if you enter this loop you have to alter the value of ukCode somewhere inside the loop (or by break(); statement) to get out of it and thus get back to your main-menu!
Your continue statement does not make any sense.

Comment: @user3192295 oh ok but what do you mean by alter the value of ukCode because ukCode is the value the program will receive from scanner input?

Answer (score 0):

try it this way:

```
    ...
    ...
    break; // where I want to return user to main menu
  } while (ukCode.equals("LPL") || ukCode.equals("BOH"));
   menu();
```

This would make your do-while loop absolutely futile, but you would get what you want.
Look into the documentation about loops to enhance your code...
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I actually, want to "return" the user to the menu so that it allows the user to select an option and go through the choices selection process again. Can I not use continue statement in some way?

Comment: 'continue' here means to continue the loop not your program. in this particular code constellation maybe it would be better without a loop. consider why you want to use a loop, whats the benefit (think for yourself)? maybe it would help to draw the flow of your program, so you can find out where to use if/else, or switch/case or while-loop or do-while etc. - And before that you should read about these concepts and what their benefits are.